# event.preventDefault(); not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

`event.preventDefault();` not working in Firefox.

```
    function submitProffs() {

        var VacBrand = document.getElementById("txtAcBrand").value;



        if (VacBrand == "") {

            alert("Please Select your Ac Brand!");
            event.preventDefault();
          }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply `event` in    `function submitProffs(event)`

```
function submitProffs(event) {
    var vacBrand = document.getElementById("txtAcBrand").value;
    if (vacBrand == "") {
        alert("Please Select your Ac Brand!");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`event` is a global variable in some browsers. There is no global `event` variable in Firefox and you should not rely on this variable. Use the event object that is passed to your event handler instead.

It seems the variable is one of many IE's non-standard features (like `document.all` and `innerText`) that other browsers (like Google Chrome) have implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You need pass argument `event` to `submitProffs` function

```
// save global scope
(function(){
 'use strict';
  // protect from hoisting
  var mainFunc,
      submitProffs;

  submitProffs = function (event) {
     var VacBrand = document.getElementById("txtAcBrand").value;
     if (VacBrand == "") {
       alert("Please Select your Ac Brand!");

       event.preventDefault();
       // if you need disable bubbling
      // event.stopPropagation();
     }
  };

  mainFunc = function (event) {
    // listen event on element
    // replace 'click' to your event
    document.addEventListener("click", submitProffs, false);
  };
  // code run when html DOM ready
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", mainFunc);
}());
```

How it works see there https://jsfiddle.net/2gew6nLo/

Answer (score 0):

In FF/Mozilla the event is passed to your event handler as a parameter. Use something like the following to get around the missing event argument in IE.

```
function onlyNumeric(e)
 {
     if (!e) {
        e = window.event;
     }

     ...
 }
```